# Initializing a string with new string("...".ToCharArray())

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have code in which some strings are initialized in the following way:

```
public static string _syncGetLanguagePackage = new string("_syncGetLanguagePackage".ToCharArray());
```

I wonder what sense this makes. Why not simply:

```
public static string _syncGetLanguagePackage = "_syncGetLanguagePackage";
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Very odd. Why not just use `nameof`?

Answer (score 3):

They wanted to duplicate the string, to have a distinct reference.

There is a better way to do it:

```
public static string _syncGetLanguagePackage = string.Copy("_syncGetLanguagePackage");
```

The [`string.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.copy?view=net-5.0) in fact:

> Creates a new instance of String with the same value as a specified String.

Answer (score 2):

The first snippet will force the creation of a new string, while the second will just initialize another variable to point to the same string literal.

Since strings in C# are immutable, for most usecases creating a new instance doesn't make a lot of sense. However there could be some exotic usecases where you need a distinct instance - e.g., if you want to use it as a synchronization mechanism.